# How to calculate positive results for a diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

"**A little pie costs 23, and a cake costs 49. Is it possible to reach 500$ selling both of the products?**"

My attempt:

$\\23x + 49y = 500 \\23x + 49y \equiv 500 \pmod{23} \\0x + 3y \equiv 17 \pmod{23} \\3y \equiv 17 \pmod{23} \\y \equiv 21 \pmod{23}\\23x+49(21+23k)=500 \\ \text{then:}\\\\x=-23-49k \\y=21+23k$

I have already tested some values and it seems to work well, the thing is:

**Is there a way** to know if I can reach **500** by only using **positive integers**? If yes, then how? I want to do so because I guess he can't sell negative pies or negative cakes, If I am wrong, please let me any hints, thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\begin{align} 
 500\, &= 49(21) + 23(-21)\\
{\rm i.e.}\ \ \ \    k\, &= \,\ m\, X\ \ +\ \ n\, Y \end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

is normalized, i.e. $0\le X < n,\,$ so by $\,Y< 0\,$ the equation $\,500 = 49X+ 23Y\,$ has no integer roots $\,X,Y\ge 0,\,$ by the Lemma in the linked dupe. See the Linked question there for many answers on this FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

you can write

$x=\frac {500-49y}{23}=21-2y+\frac {17-3y}{23}$,

Since  $49y\leq500,y\leq10$,

therefore $-13\leq17-3y\leq17$,

I believe you can easily get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

> $x=−23 −49k$. 
> $y=21+23k$.

Assuming that the above work is accurate, and that it is desired that both $x$ and $y$ be non-negative and that $k$ must be an integer:

- The first equation above requires that $k < 0$, else $x < 0$.
- The second equation requires that $k \geq 0$, else $y < 0$.

Therefore, there is no integer value of $k$ that will make both $x$ and $y$ non-negative.

Comment: This is a special case of the Lemma in the linked dupe. Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).